# Is there any way to get delay of specific time using persistence database like redis?

Tags: events, redis, delay

I want to insert a delay of 30 minutes between two function call for eg:
sending email after 30 minutes once fcm/sms is sent.

I'm trying to use Redis for this so I'm using node module name bull which allows me to create a job with the delay and push it inside the queue.
//sending sms to user
sms(null, {to: phone,content: {msg: "test message"},sender: "XYZ"});

// here I have to add a delay of 30 minutes

// sending notification to user 
fcm(null,{user_ids: userId,message: "restart!!!"});

I don't want to use setTimeout as it will not work if my app will restart.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using bull https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull this package contains the option to add delays in the milliseconds:-
For example, adding a delay of 30 mins

```
providerDelayedQueue.add(options, { delay: 1800000 });
```

The above job will be consumed at least after a delay of 30 mins.